# Assign value from succesfull promise resolve to mutable ref object in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, rest

I'm creating a random movie generator, for that I'm calling an external API to get the movies, and then I'm selecting one movie from the returned list. I managed to make it work like this:

```
export default function Page() {
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState<Movie>({
    title: ""
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    setNewMovie()
  }, [])

  function setNewMovie() {
    getMoviesRequest().then((newMovies) => {
      const randomIndex = getRandomInt(9)
      const movie = newMovies[randomIndex]
      setMovie(movie)
    })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>
        {movie.title}
      </h3>
      <button onClick={setNewMovie}>
        Generate New Movie
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The problem with this code is that it has to call the API every time I want to set a new movie, which is not ideal since it takes longer to run. What I would like to do is call the API once within the `useEffect` hook and have the returned movies stay the same throughout the hole lifetime of the component so that I don't have to pull the list of movies on every render. I'm  using `useRef` to achieve this, here's what I've tryied:

```
export default function Page() {
  const movies = useRef<Movie[]>([])
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState<Movie>({
    title: ""
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    setNewMovies()
    setNewMovie()
  }, [])

  function setNewMovies() {
    getMoviesRequest().then((newMovies) => {
      movies.current = newMovies
    })
  }
  function setNewMovie() {
    const randomIndex = getRandomInt(9)
    const movie = movies.current[randomIndex]
    setMovie(movie)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>
        {movie.title}
      </h3>
      <button onClick={setNewMovie}>
        Generate New Movie
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This isn't working since if I try to access the current value of `movies` outside the promise It seems to not have been updated.

I looked for answers and I found that you can't really access the value of the promise from outside unless you are on an async function, but I already tryied that and I get the same result.

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this code

```
setNewMovies()
setNewMovie()
```

is that `setNewMovies` is async and you need to wait for it to end till you can do the other action. You could have a method called `getMoviesFromCacheOrApi` that would either return the ref value or get the movies from api and then store it in ref if the ref value is not set. I would use `null` as the initial value for the ref because you may have an empty array returned by the api but you should know better what it returns in your case.

Below is an example of what I wanted to say.

```
export default function Page() {
  const cachedMoviesFromApi = useRef<Movie[] | null>(null)
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState<Movie>({
    title: ""
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    setNewMovie().then()
  }, [])

  async function getMoviesFromCacheOrApi() {
    if (cachedMoviesFromApi.current) {
      return cachedMoviesFromApi.current
    }

    const moviesFromApi = await getMoviesRequest()
    cachedMoviesFromApi.current = moviesFromApi

    return moviesFromApi
  }

  async function setNewMovie() {
    const movies = await getMoviesFromCacheOrApi()
    const randomIndex = getRandomInt(9)
    const movie = movies[randomIndex]

    setMovie(movie)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>
        {movie.title}
      </h3>
      <button onClick={setNewMovie}>
        Generate New Movie
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, now I understand why it wasn't working.